# Change .tld in Apify-ready templates

Tags: web-crawler, apify

is it possible to change the top level domain in ready-made templates (like the Tripadvisor Crawler) in the Apify store? The goal is to get not only the english comments, but also the german, french, etc comments. How can I adapt the script without writing a new crawler?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ready-made actors from the Store, you are completely in the hands of the actor author. Each actor works a bit differently although we are trying to make a similar template for the input.

Some public actors allow you to pass whole URLs so you can change the tld there. Some allow you to select the country directly in the input.

If any of these is not available in the input, it is usually the best to create an issue on the actor's Github source page so the author will implement it. You can also make the pull request with the change yourself.